# Происхождение выражения "держать в черном теле"

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение выражения "держать в черном теле" — то есть, плохо с кем-то обращаться. Могу предположить, что речь идет о грязи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оборот "держать в черном теле" - тюркизм из коневодческой терминологии. В тюркских языках цветообозначение к ъ а р а (буквально "черный") может употребляться в значении "чистый, без примеси". Тюркское выражение к ъ а р а а т (дословно "черное мясо") употребляется как наименование нежирного мяса или вырезки, где нет белых жировых прослоек. Первоначальный смысл выражения "держать в черном теле" был "питать умеренно, не давать жиреть, чтобы мясо было лишено жировых прослоек, было темным", но потом постепенно возобладал смысл "держать в физических лишениях", отзвук которого слышится в этом обороте и сейчас. http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2_%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5

Comment: Надо же, как интересно!